# how to use selenium wait.until with anchor element in java

Tags: c#, java, selenium-webdriver

i have selenium project written in c# and i want to migrate it to java, but i have a problem that i could not solve by myself. 
lets say i have a `webElement elem1` and i want to find another element `elem2` using `elem1` as the anchor.
so in java i can do it like that:

```
WebElement elem1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.uiContextualLayer.uiContextualLayerBelowLeft"))) ;

WebElement elem2 = elem1.findElement(By.tagName("li"));
```

now, my problem starts when i want to do the same but with `wait.until()` for `elem2`. the thing is that `elem1` is always appear in the DOM, but `elem2` will appear in the DOM only after some time (it depends on some code that is not relevant for this issue), so using the above code will throw an exception.
in c# i used lambda expression and it was very simple:

```
IWebElement elem1 = wait.Until((d) => { return d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.uiContextualLayer.uiContextualLayerBelowLeft")); });

IWebElement elem2= wait.Until((d) => { return **elem1**.FindElement(By.TagName("li")); });
```

in java i cant find a way to do the `wait.until` AND use `elem1` as the anchor for the `findElement` function.
here is a sample of the html i'm working on:

```
<div class="uiContextualLayer uiContextualLayerBelowLeft">
      <div style="width: 240px;">
          <div class="uiTypeaheadView uiContextualTypeaheadView">
              <ul id="typeahead_list_u_jsonp_2_2" class="search" role="listbox">
                  <li id="js_2" class="user" aria-label="whatEver" role="option" aria-selected="false">
                      <a href="someLink" rel="ignore" target=""> … </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

i don't want to get all the elements that has the "li" tagName into a list and than go over each element to find the element i need. i'm pretty sure i'm missing something which is very basic, and would appreciate any suggestion/explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most Java-style way is to have methods that return locators and write your own inline `ExpectedCondition` that uses these methods.

```
public By getElem1Locator() {
    return By.cssSelector(....);
}
public By getElem2Locator() {
    return By.tagName(....);
}

...

    WebElement elem2 = wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
                return driver.findElement(getElem1Locator()).findElement(getElem2Locator());
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return null;
        }
    });

...
```

The reason why we want to use locators and not final `WebElement` instances is that if DOM changes while we are waiting, the `WebElement` can become stale.

A quick and dirty solution is to use a single Xpath selector for the second element

```
WebElement elem2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' uiContextualLayer ') and contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' uiContextualLayerBelowLeft ')]//li"));
```

You should also take a look at [Page Factory](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory)

Comment: I just now tried your solution. Works as (you) expected. thank you very much!